# Не работает scrollTo

Tags: android

Код:

```
    TableRow cr = (TableRow) findViewById(R.id.crdesc);
    ScrollView scr = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrr);
    scr.scrollTo(0, cr.getTop());
```

Строение активити:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private void postScroll(final int x, final int y) {
    scrollView.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            scrollView.scrollTo(x, y);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: не помогло

Comment: не может быть, значит не правильно используешь

Comment: С postScroll(0, 400) заработало, но с postScroll(0, cr.getTop()) никак

Comment: подебаж или выведи в лог cr.getTop(), посмотри какое там значение

Comment: В лог вывести не получается - лог.в думает, что ему дают ресурс из-за типа int

Comment: А может работает не так как хотелось? Уточните - что именно не так?
как вариант (с гадалкой)) :
scrollView.requestChildFocus(null, cr);

и самое главное до findView было  setContent ?

Comment: @woesss а requestChildFocus то что надо - сработало